# Why is my does my array need to be integers or slices?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

When i press the button at line 26
the command at line 17 is getting triggered.
The function is that the entry at line 30
is getting added to the array at line 18.
Now when i press the download button at line 34
the command at line 12 is getting triggered.  Error im getting = TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

my intention is to add more names to the array and let the download function at line 12 goes through all the names in the array
can somebody help me

i tried to find answers on forums like this but because of my coding skills its very hard to understand answers that are specially for the askers

```py
import instaloader
import tkinter as tk


GUI = tk.Tk()

loader = instaloader.Instaloader(download_comments=False, download_geotags=False, 
                                     save_metadata=False, download_video_thumbnails=False)  #Voreinstellung für Download (preset for download)

Instaname = []

def download():                                 #Download command           (download command)
    for i in Instaname:
        loader.download_profile(Instaname[i])   #Command für Downloadziel   (command for download target)


def hinzufügen():                               #Hinzufügen command         (Add button)
        Instaname.append(entryUser.get())       #Name, Array hinzufügen     (add name to array)
        

#Fenstergröße (Window)
canvas = tk.Canvas(GUI, height=100, width=200)
canvas.pack()

#Hinzufügenbutton (Addbutton)
addnamebutton = tk.Button(GUI, text="Name hinzufügen",command=hinzufügen)
addnamebutton.pack()

#ZielUsernameEntry (TargetUsernameEntry)
entryUser = tk.Entry(GUI)
entryUser.pack()

#Downloadbutton    (Downloadbutton)
downbutton = tk.Button(GUI, text="Download", command=download, bg="blue", cursor="target")
downbutton.pack()

GUI.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the elements of `Instaname` as indices back into the same list:

```
    for i in Instaname:
        loader.download_profile(Instaname[i])
```

Instead, just use the elements directly:

```
    for i in Instaname:
        # each i is a different string from Instaname
        loader.download_profile(i)
```

If you wanted to iterate over the indices of `Instaname`, you'd build a `range` of the indices and then iterate over that:

```
    for i in range(len(Instaname)):
        # now each i is an int between 0 and len(Instaname)-1
        loader.download_profile(Instaname[i])
```